# How to handle belongs_to relation in Kohana ORM

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana

Let's say I have 2 models:

```
class Model_Student extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'student_id' => array(),
        'first_name' => array(),
        'last_name' => array()
    );

    protected $_has_one = array(
        'phone' => array()
    )
}
```

and

```
class Model_Phone extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'student_id' => array(),
        'number' => array(),
    );

    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'student' => array()
    )
}
```

How can I create a new phone object and add it to a user?

Is this the correct way?

```
$student = ORM::factory('student', 1); // Load student with id=1
$phone = ORM::factory('phone');
$phone->student_id = $student->student_id;
$phone->number = '1234567890';
$phone->save();
```

In this case I made the connection manually:

```
$phone->student_id = $student->student_id;
```

Can ORM make this connection automatically? If yes, how?

I would like to make something like this:

```
$student = ORM::factory('student', 1); // Load student with id=1
$phone = ORM::factory('phone');
$phone->number = '1234567890';
$student->add('phone', $phone);
```

But *add* is (as I know) for many to many connections.
So how to save the phone model and attach it to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no such method for one-to-one relationships. So your is the correct way to do this:

```
$student = ORM::factory('student', 1); // Load student with id=1
$phone = ORM::factory('phone');
$phone->student_id = $student->student_id;
$phone->number = '1234567890';
$phone->save();
```

But in your case don't want to store phone in the separate table as it's only make things more complicated. Just add phone column to the users table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PK different from 'id' (students.student_id), make sure your model knows it:

```
class Model_Student extends ORM
{
    protected $_primary_key = 'student_id';

    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'student_id' => array(),
        'first_name' => array(),
        'last_name' => array()
    );

    protected $_has_one = array(
        'phone' => array()
    )
}
```

Also you can omit $_table_columns - just let Kohana discover them itself.

And about relations: you can do this things:

```
$student = ORM::factory('student', 1); // Load student with id=1
$phone = ORM::factory('phone');
$phone->student = $student;
$phone->number = '1234567890';
$phone->save();

// ------------

$phone = ORM::factory('phone', 1);
echo $phone->student->first_name;

// ------------

$student = ORM::factory('student', 1);
echo $student->phone->number;
```